# how to read from a file in to a struct in c

Tags: c

I have this struct.

```
Struct Wizard{
 char name[50];
 int maxHealth;
 int attackMin, attackRange;
 int curHealth, winCount;
};
```

And I need to make a function save the stats to a txt file.
I was given this bit of code to start it.

```
int saveWiz(struct Wizard * wiz)
{
  File * fp = fopen("champion.txt","w");
  char * buff = malloc(100);
  sprintf(buff,... );
  sprintf(buff,...);
  //Todo: replace ... with appropriate string, using tags like %d for variables
  fputs(buff,fp);
  fclose(fp);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I think I am supposed to use the wiz pointer to access the struct but I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: Read from a file into a struct? Or write a struct into a file?

Comment: It's not a very good bit of code to start with.  There does not seem to be much point in mallocating the file output buffer, may as well use an auto storage local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand exactly what you are asking but I'm guessing it's this:

You have a wiz variable of type struct Wizard * . You access the elements like this : wiz->name , wiz->maxHealth and so on, 
wiz->name is equivalent to (*wiz).name . So you'll have :

```
int saveWiz(struct Wizard * wiz)  //assuming you return 1 for success 0 for failure
{
  File * fp = fopen("champion.txt","w");
  if(!fp) {
    //file opening failed
   return 0;
}
  char * buff = malloc(200); // 200 to be sure
  if(buff) {
  sprintf(buff,"%s",wiz->name);
  sprintf(buff,"%d %d %d %d %d" , wiz->maxHealth,  wiz->attackMin,    wiz->attackRange, wiz->curHealth, wiz->winCount);
  fputs(buff,fp);
  fclose(fp);
  free(buff);
  return 1;
  }
else {
   //memory allocation failed
return 0;
}

}
```

Also as Martin James pointed out it is best to free dynamically allocated memory after you're done using it ( otherwise causes ugly memory leaks on long-running programs) . On that note , it's also good to check if the file opening was successful as well as the memory allocation. Also another thing I noticed is the number of elements in the buff array , 100 might not be enough ( considering an int is 32 bit (10 digits) and the name has a full 50 characters, along with the spaces it might cause an overflow).

Comment: Leaks buff, returns nothing:(

Comment: @MartinJames thank you, I edited it , I was focused on filling up the blanks, I didn't look at the overall correctness.